# How to do cascaded dropdown in an edit view using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, controller, cascadingdropdown

I have created a cascading dropdown for my application, on the create it works fine but I am struggling to implement the same on the edit. Please find the code below.

Ho do I use the same methodology for getting all the cascaded values for the edit so the user can know what are the associated values to the main cascaded dropdown?

CREATE

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IndicatorID, "Indicator", htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
"control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IndicatorID, new SelectList(ViewBag.IndicatorID as 
   System.Collections.IEnumerable, "IndicatorID", "IndicatorName"),
   "Select a Indicator", new { id = "ddlIndicators" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IndicatorID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IndGrID, "Group  IndGrID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
"control-label col-md-2" })

<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.IndGrID, new 
    SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "GroupId", "GroupName"),
"Select a Subgroup", new { id = "ddlGroup" })
   
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IndGrID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubGroupID, "Sub Group SubGroupID", htmlAttributes: new { @class 
= "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.SubGroupID, new 
SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "SubGroupID", "SubGroupName"),
"Select a Subgroup", new { id = "ddlSubGroup" })
      
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubGroupID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlIndicators").change(function () {
        var indicatorID = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("../Indicator_SubGroup/LoadSubGroupByIndicatorID", { indicatorID: 
 indicatorID },
 function (classesData) {
                var select = $("#ddlGroup");
                select.empty();
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: 0,
                    text: "Select group"
                }));
                $.each(classesData, function (index, itemData) {
                    //alert(classesData);
                    //alert(itemData);
                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));
                });
            });
    });

 $("#ddlGroup").change(function () {
        var subGroupId = $(this).val();
         $.getJSON("../Indicator_SubGroup/LoadSubGroupByGroupID", { subGroupId: subGroupId 
 },
       
            function (marksData) {
                var select = $("#ddlSubGroup");
                select.empty();
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: 0,
                    text: "Select Subgroup"
                }));
                $.each(marksData, function (index, itemData) {
                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));
                });
            });
    });
```

Controller:

```
private IList<Ref_Indicator_Group> GetGroup(int groupid)
{
return db.Ref_Indicator_Group.Where(m => m.GroupId == groupid).ToList();
}

private IList<Ref_SubGroup> GetSubGroup(int subGroupid)
{
return db.Ref_SubGroup.Where(m => m.Indicator_GroupID == subGroupid).ToList();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult LoadSubGroupByIndicatorID(/*string groupid*/int indicatorID)
{
var gi = db.INDICATORS.Where(d => d.IndicatorID == indicatorID).FirstOrDefault();
var subgrouplist = this.GetGroup(Convert.ToInt32(gi.GroupID));
var subgroupData = subgrouplist.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = m.GroupName,
        Value = m.GroupId.ToString(),
    });

return Json(subgroupData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult LoadSubGroupByGroupID(string subGroupId)
{
var subgroupList = this.GetSubGroup(Convert.ToInt32(subGroupId));
var subgroupData = subgroupList.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = c.SubGroupName,
        Value = c.SubGroupID.ToString(),
    });

return Json(subgroupData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

EDIT

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

Indicator_SubGroup indicator_SubGroup = db.Indicator_SubGroup.Find(id);

if (indicator_SubGroup == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}

ViewBag.IndicatorID = new SelectList(db.INDICATORS, "IndicatorID", "IndicatorName", 
indicator_SubGroup.IndicatorID);
ViewBag.SubGroupID = new SelectList(db.Ref_SubGroup, "SubGroupID", "SubGroupName", 
indicator_SubGroup.SubGroupID);
ViewBag.IndGrID = new SelectList(db.Ref_Indicator_Group, "GroupId", "GroupName", 
indicator_SubGroup.IndGrID);

return View(indicator_SubGroup);
}
```

Comment: Is your create and edit `Action` in a different controller? Also, you've only posted the `CREATE` cshtml code, assuming the edit is very similar?

Comment: @Izzy yes sorry I have changed it and made it clear...can you help with this?